# Devicemotion event on iOS

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, device-orientation, webapi, devicemotion

I want to implement mobile device "shake" event both for Android and iOS platforms on my webpage.

So, I immediately found one and only [script](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js) written by Alex Gibson.

After some tests I found out that it works on Android phone perfectly. On iPhone it doesn't work unfortunately.

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicemotion_event) it's nothing wrong with the script which uses `devicemotion` event.

This script on [codeopen](https://codepen.io/mrtester/pen/PoqQjYG) with no errors for iOS, just not working.

Is there any approach to overcome this issue?

**U.P.D.**

I found [this article](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-request-device-motion-and-orientation-permission-in-ios-13-74fc9d6cd140) describing requirements for iOS 13 for `devicemotion` event, so now you have to request permission for it.

But it also doesn't work.

```
window.DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  }
})
```

It returns 'denied' status anyway without any permission request.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too. requestPermission for the devicemotion event is always denied (silently) by iOS 13+, but only if you are running your site on http.

It worked (for me at least) if I ran my site on https.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried it on Codepen with https by default, it didn't work for me.